# Wildfly: Using Spring @Autowired for UserTransaction

Tags: java, spring, maven, wildfly

During my migration from Jboss AS5 to Wildfly9 for an application , I am trying to load a module in wildfly: javax.transaction.api 
Looking at [Wildfly article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments) to load modules in WF8 , it says that you may not need to load some modules explicitly as they are loaded implicitly.

I am using in one of my classes

```
 @Autowired
private UserTransaction transaction;
```

then I define it in applictionContext.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="userTransaction" jndi-name="UserTransaction" expected-type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"/>
```

in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
 <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
```

but i get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
private javax.transaction.UserTransaction com.mycomp.myapp.EventSender.transaction; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [javax.transaction.UserTransaction] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I tried to add the jta.jar into the lib of the war, i tried to add the dependencies of the jta. I tried to add javax.transaction only just in case, they all didnt work. I am not getting `ClassNotfoundexception` or `ClassCastexception`. Everything seems to be so straightforward. I am failing to understand what is missing here.

> "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myApp" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myApp: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppManager' defined in \"/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/bin/content/myApp-engine-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycomp/myApp/myAppManager.class\": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [com.mycomp.myApp.EventSender]: : Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppManager' defined in \"/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/bin/content/myApp-engine-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycomp/myApp/myAppManager.class\": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [com.mycomp.myApp.EventSender]: : Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppManager' defined in \"/C:/JAVA/WF9/wildfly-9.0.0.Final/bin/content/myApp-engine-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mycomp/myApp/myAppManager.class\": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [com.mycomp.myApp.EventSender]: : Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>   Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EventSender': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction
>       Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.UserTransaction"}},
>       "rolled-back" => true

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the stacktrace:

```
'userTransaction': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction
```

The bean could not be created because the JNDI lookup failed. There is no resource named "UserTransaction" available on your app server.

Comment: I think that the javax.transaction.UserTransaction is the resource to which the JNDI is pointing to. that is part of the jta.jar which is added as a module. it seems that it cannot see the jta.jar even though i have added as a module or even tried adding it as a jar in the WEB-INF/lib as a library.

Comment: That is the type of the resource. If you are deploying into Wildfly, you do not need to add the jta.jar, it is a part of the app server. The stack trace states you have the wrong value in jndi-name. The jndi-name "UserTransaction" looks wrong to me. I would expect something like "java:jboss/UserTransaction" or "java:comp/UserTransaction".

Comment: Thanks sh0rug0ru : java:jboss/UserTransaction  did the trick. Strangely, I have two more jndi lookups one is a connection factory and it is java:/JmsXA and it works, and the other is an eis which is having the jndi-name: java:/eis/myeis, and that works as well. the JmsXa is also coming from javax,jms.Connection, i had even tried java:/UserTransaction but that did not work i had to add the jboss in there for it to work.